# change the Jquery attribute after clicking

Tags: jquery, css, click, html

I would like to create a single button on my webpage that's function changes after being clicked on. In this case I would like to slide a div to a smaller size then use the same button to re size it up.
The code I have tried so far is as follows

```
$('#full-view').click(function(){
    $('.right').animate({width:"2%"},'fast');
    $('#full-view').click(function(){
        $('.right').animate({width:"15%"},'fast');
    });
});
```

This current method however causes the div.right to shrink in size but immediately re-expand.
I imagine this question might have already been asked but I cant seam to work out the correct search. Is the Jquery click function the same as talking about the onclick attribute?

Comment: JQuery click() is the same as the pure JS onclick pretty much

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#full-view').click(function(){
    $('.right').animate({width:"2%"},'fast');
    $('#full-view').on('click',function(){
        $('.right').animate({width:"15%"},'fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable to keep track of the size and then just detect whether the div needs to grow or shrink

```
var is_small = false;
$('#full-view').click(function(){
    if(is_small){
        $('.right').animate({width:"15%"},'fast');
        is_samll = true;
    }else {
         $('.right').animate({width:"2%"},'fast');
         is_small = false;
    }
}
```